# Generating google chart from mysql column with accent

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm generating google charts from different months in a year. Every month seems to work fine except for months(février) with accent. It has an error message saying Table has no column. In the mysql table I have a column like this (1-févr), (2-févr) ...  Is the accent the cause of the error? If so, how could I fix it?
Thanks!

EDIT: I realised the problem is with JSON_encode, and all I needed to do is to use the utf8_encode function to my data before I convert them to JSON.

Comment: `utf8_encode()` converts from ISO-8859-1. Is your application actually using ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Is `1-févr` a column _name_?  Or the _contents_ of some column?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the column form the database use backticks surrounding the column name, so the query before would look like so:

```
SELECT 1-févr, 2-févr FROM table
```

This would need to be changed to:

```
SELECT `1-févr`, `2-févr` FROM table
```

Please be careful, these are backticks and not quotes ie it is ` and not ' or ".

This ensures the string is evaluated as a whole and not broken due to characters such as hyphens etc.

Comment: I have a query like this
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $tablename ."`";
which I go on to generate google chart with something like this
 $table['cols'] = array(    

    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'EDF', 'type' => 'number')

);
Funny it works for marsr(march), avril(April) and mai(May) and not février.